# How do sentence intonation and (syllable-based) tone interact in tone languages?

Tags: phonology, phonetics, tone, intonation

**Tone languages** use intonation to distinguish words. For example, in [Mandarin Chinese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tonal_language#Mechanics)

> *mā* with a mid tone means *mom*
>
> *mǎ* with a rising tone means *horse*

**Intonation languages** do not make such distinctions. Intonation is only used to distinguish the meaning of sentences. English

> Berry is coming home tonight.

is a statement with falling intonation, but a question with rising intonation.

However, tone languages also use intonation in this way, in addition to its phonemic function of distinguishing words. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intonation_%28linguistics%29#Intonation_in_Mandarin_Chinese) says that in Mandarin Chinese

> tones create fluctuations of pitch around the sentence patterns [...]. Thus the sentence patterns can be thought of as bands whose pitch varies over the course of the sentence, while changes of syllable pitch cause fluctuations within the band.

So tones consist of smaller variations and sentence intonation causes greater variations.

**Q: Is this a common or universal pattern in tone languages? Are there other ways in which syllable-level tone and sentence-level intonation interact in tone languages?**

Comment: Some tonal languages apparently do not use rising intonation for questions at all. I'm travelling in Thailand right now and have just read not to do this in Thai. Instead Thai has question particles which must be present at the end of a question and all tones are unaltered.

Comment: "> *mā* with a mid tone means *mom*> *mǎ* with a rising tone means *horse*" ,such description is not correct, the former one is high tone and keep almost stable to the end(55). the latter is curved tone, which begins at half-low(2), falls to low(1),and rises to the half-high(4). Chao, Y. R says,"Each tone-letter consists of a vertical reference line, of the hight of an n, to which a simplified time-pitch curve of the tone represented is attached. The total range is divided into four equal parts,thus making five points,[to be continued]

Comment: [cont]  numberd 1,2,3,4,5, correspongding to low, half-low,medium, half-high, high, respectively"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The "ripples on waves" (Bolinger 1964, Chao 1968) interaction that is observed in Mandarin is only one of several ways that lexical tone and utterance-level intonation may interact.**

I did a series of production experiments in which I elicited sets of utterances from native speakers of tone languages; the main two variables I manipulated were the tone on the final word or syllable and the intonation-type of the utterance (either declarative or echo question). The following summarizes what I found for echo question as opposed to declarative intonation in each language:

Mandarin: The local contour of the lexical tone on the final syllable was largely preserved but shifted upward in the speaker's vocal range. So a falling lexical tone was still falling but from a higher starting pitch.

Cantonese: The first half of the final syllable preserved information about the lexical tone on that syllable, but starting somewhere in the middle of the syllable the pitch shot upward with a steep incline. So a falling tone started falling but after the initial dip the pitch shot up in the second half of the syllable. There was no major lengthening of the syllable to accommodate both trajectories.

Shiga Japanese: The tone and the intonation were expressed "in series", so that the fall associated with the lexical tone was completed and then the syllable was extended to accommodate the subsequent rise associated with the echo question intonation. In some cases this lengthening nearly tripled the duration of the final syllable.

North Kyeongsang Korean: If the final word was monosyllabic, the falling contour observed in the declarative case was completely "overwritten" by a rising contour. If the final word was disyllabic (where the peak was on the first syllable and the fall carried through to the end of the second syllable in the declarative case) the fall was preserved but it started higher in the speaker's range on the first syllable (much like in Mandarin). In some instances there was a slight rise toward the end of the syllable (like in Cantonese, but nowhere near the magnitude observed in Cantonese or in the monosyllabic case).

Interestingly, in each language there were lexical-tone-specific idiosyncrasies that made it impossible to formally characterize the mapping from the declarative version of a lexical tonal contour to the echo question version beyond the descriptive generalizations above. In other words, for a given language it was not possible to come up with an algorithm that could accurately predict the F0 contour of an echo question given only the F0 contour of its declarative counterpart. For example, There are three tones in Cantonese that are basically level in the declarative environment. In two out of the three cases (tone 3 and tone 6), the rising trajectory in the echo question environment was curved (i.e. more exponential-looking) but in the third case (tone 1) it was straight (i.e. more linear-looking).

@jlawler's comment reminded me that there is also an interesting case in Shingazidja, a Bantu language spoken in the Comoros. Patin (2008) shows data suggesting that yes-no questions in Shingazidja are formed by the insertion of a "superhigh" tone on the penultimate syllable (phonetically the pitch on the syllable is higher than that on lexically H-toned syllables), overwriting whatever is there in the declarative version of the utterance (it gets realized at the same pitch regardless of the tone on that penultimate syllable in the declarative version). Interestingly, when the final syllable of the declarative version of the utterance bears a lexical H tone, the superhigh intonational tone is placed on the *antepenultimate* syllable!

Bolinger, D. (1964). "Intonation: around the edge of language." Harvard Educational Review 34: 282-296.

Chao, Y. R. (1968). A Grammar of Spoken Chinese. Berkeley, CA, University of California Press.

Patin, C. (2008). Tone and Intonation's Waltz in Shingazidja Polar Questions. 3rd TIE
Conference on Tone and Intonation (TIE3). Lisbonne.

Comment: Fascinating results, thank you! Have you published the results anywhere? Regarding your results for Japanese, I once talked to a Japanese (linguist) friend of mine and she indicated that a mora may be added (at the end of the sentence? don't really remember...) to preserve sentence intonation. Would this be compatible with your lengthening analysis?

Comment: See also [Downstep](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Downstep), which is a prominent feature in African tone languages, at least.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how downstep addresses the question how word-level tone and utterance-level intonation interact. Does downstep ever have any pragmatic meaning like marking an utterance as a question?

Comment: @robert, I haven't published the results anywhere except in my dissertation, haha! I did consider mora insertion as a possible analysis for the Japanese results. The only argument against it would be the lack of consistency in the amount of lengthening, both among different speakers and also for one speaker (usually if the echo question is more emphatic there is more lengthening).

Comment: Is it available via academia.edu or another outlet?

Comment: In standard Japanese, since lexical tone is inter-moraic, wouldn't that leave mora-internal tone open for sentence-level intonation, with no lengthening needed? That's how I usually interpret standard Japanese echo questions. Rising on the last mora, with the beginning of the last mora following usual downstep rules. Possible lengthening solely for emphasis.

Comment: @dainichi, I'm not sure what you mean by "inter-moraic", but in my experiments (on Shiga Japanese) the degree of lengthening was greatest when the final mora was specified for tone (and therefore was _not_ "open for use" by intonation). This happened when the word was final-accented with a monomoraic final syllable (_ame_ 'rain') so that the last syllable was specified for both a H and a L tone in the declarative, and in the echo question three different pitch targets needed to fit on that last mora--the lexical H and L and the subsequent intonational H.

Comment: I haven't done formal experimentation on this with standard Japanese, but anecdotally I have observed that in words where the final syllable is accented and bimoraic there is often lengthening in the echo question; one possible interpretation of this behavior is that the final mora in such words is not "open for use" because it is specified for the lexical L associated with the accent. The degree of lengthening may not be as much as in the Shiga case I mentioned, though, because in this case there are only two and not three pitch targets being associated with that last mora.

Comment: @robert, I don't think it's available online at the moment, but I think it's going to be soon. If and when it is I'll try to remember to update you!

Comment: I don't know Shiga-Japanese, so it's a bit hard for me to follow, but what I meant was that to turn SJ 雨 H+L and 飴 L+H into echo questions, it's possible to do 雨？H+(L rising) and 飴? L+(high rising). Of course, fitting the rising part within one mora might be unclear, which I guess is why lengthening is common (but not mandatory).

Comment: @dainichi Almost. The full tonal pattern for 雨 is LHL (where the HL is on the second mora), so it's fitting both a falling _and_ a rising all on one mora in that case. All else being equal 雨? tends to get lengthened more than 飴?, which suggests that the lengthening cannot be solely due to emphasis.

Comment: I see, thanks. I assume 雨 LHL is Shiga-Japanese and not an alternative analysis of SJ 雨. I wouldn't be surprised, though, if even in SJ, "雨?" tends to get lengthened more often than "飴?"